# How can I put >1000 strings in an array & make them searchable?

Tags: java, android, string

I'm learning to code by myself (Java and Android) and I'm working on creating an application for Android.

It's a language application (Grammar) to analyze verb.

What I have currently is I have a list of 1000 verb and each one has it's own way of forms and I'm stuck to find way to store them as strings but don't want to use a lot of string or too long array.

I was thinking of array of string but an array to have 1000 string not sure if this is really practical.

I thought of creating what I need in an excel and then to use this excel as the storage where the app can use it to search in it and show the results found there in a `TextView` but again not quite sure if this will work with Android.

Let's say I have the below 3 verbs in infinitive

1. Akl
2. ktv
3. hlk

Now the first verb can come in another 2 forms (Nakl - Hikel) and the other verbs too have their own forms.

What I want to do is, when a user type the verb whether in past or present for example (Akled "past" or hikeling "present") the system will substring only the verb by removing the ending and then use what is left (for example: akled ---> akl) to show the other forms, in this case if it is "akled" then system will use "akl" and show nakl - hikel.

Example:

1. User type in text box (akled) and press analyse
2. System will do the following:
   substring the verb only (akl)
3. then based on this verb will show other forms, which are (nakl - hikel).

Is this doable with huge number of verbs? Let's say each verb has only 2 other forms, so based on this the 1000 verb has 2000 other forms.

Comment: I'd use a `HashMap<String,String>`, with an entry for each form of each verb.  Use the inflected form as the key, and the infinitive as the value.

Comment: have you trying using a properties file where you can store all the strings there and then you can load that on the app when needed?

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem
Thank you for the hint, will think about it and try it.

Comment: @PavulZavala
Would you show me an example, I don't understand what is properties file? Is it a file to create in android studio?

Comment: .properties files are files were you store a lot of string in "name=value" format, are common used in java, here you can see several examples: https://www.mkyong.com/java/java-properties-file-examples/, I remember android have their only  string.xml file where you are supposed to store all strings there, then you can get those strings with their ID

Comment: @PavulZavala
Great I'll give it a try too. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Don't bother about loading too many strings in the memory. Strings are internally represented as array of characters and `char` type in Java takes 2 bytes. So, if you were to keep 100,000 strings (each 20 characters long), then the total memory occupied by the String[] of 100,000 elements will be 100,000 * 20 * 2 = 4,000,000 bytes = 4 MB. And JVM heap size is usually in Gigabytes, so you shouldn't be bothered about whether you should load this much strings in memory or not. Even if you load 10 times the above, i.e. 1,000,000 strings, you'll be occupying only 40 MB of memory.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

you can create your own String resource files in android, where you can store there all the strings used on the app: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource

above link will show you the format to use, where to put that file of strings in your android project and how to use it.

on this link you have an example of how to get an string array from resources:
https://www.android-examples.com/get-string-array-from-strings-xml-in-android/